# Replace a text with trackchange which present inside a hyperlink element - Docx4j

Tags: docx4j

I'm trying to replace a text with trackchange which present inside a hyperlink element.
I'm using **replacetext_2_0** bookmark for find value. I tried couple of logics but not received the expected output. Can anyone help me to resolve this.
Namespace which I tried given below:

```
1. <w:hyperlink r:id=\""+((Hyperlink) temp).getId()+"\" xmlns:w=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main\">

2. <w:hyperlink r:id=\""+((Hyperlink) temp).getId()+"\" xmlns:dsp=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2008/diagram\" xmlns:cppr=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/coverPageProps\" xmlns:odx=\"http://opendope.org/xpaths\" xmlns:c14=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2007/8/2/chart\" xmlns:xdr=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/spreadsheetDrawing\" xmlns:odgm=\"http://opendope.org/SmartArt/DataHierarchy\" xmlns:w16se=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2015/wordml/symex\" xmlns:wp14=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingDrawing\" xmlns:dgm=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/diagram\" xmlns:pic=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture\" xmlns:we=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/webextensions/webextension/2010/11\" xmlns:pvml=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:powerpoint\" xmlns:mc=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006\" xmlns:w10=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word\" xmlns:sl=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/schemaLibrary/2006/main\" xmlns:wp=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing\" xmlns:w15=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2012/wordml\" xmlns:w14=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml\" xmlns:a=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main\" xmlns:comp=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/compatibility\" xmlns:b=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/bibliography\" xmlns:c=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/chart\" xmlns:xvml=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel\" xmlns:m=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math\" xmlns:oda=\"http://opendope.org/answers\" xmlns:wne=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml\" xmlns:o=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office\" xmlns:odc=\"http://opendope.org/conditions\" xmlns:cdr=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/chartDrawing\" xmlns:r=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships\" xmlns:odi=\"http://opendope.org/components\" xmlns:v=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml\" xmlns:w=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main\" xmlns:lc=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/lockedCanvas\" xmlns:odq=\"http://opendope.org/questions\" xmlns:wetp=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/webextensions/taskpanes/2010/11\" xmlns:w16cid=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2016/wordml/cid\">
```

Received below error even after adding the namespace.

**StackTrace:**

```
[org.docx4j.XmlUtils$LoggingErrorListener:main:1554] - The prefix "w" for element "w:hyperlink" is not bound.
; Line#: 1; Column#: 26
javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: The prefix "w" for element "w:hyperlink" is not bound.
```

Find value: Age of 18 years

Replace value: Age of 18

**Sample Input:**

```
     <w:p>
        <w:pPr>
            <w:pStyle w:val="ChapterTitle"/>
            <w:spacing w:before="0" w:after="0"/>
            <w:jc w:val="both"/>
            <w:rPr>
                <w:rStyle w:val="Heading1Char"/>
                <w:rFonts w:cs="Arial"/>
                <w:b w:val="false"/>
                <w:bCs w:val="false"/>
                <w:color w:val="000000" w:themeColor="text1"/>
                <w:sz w:val="22"/>
                <w:szCs w:val="22"/>
                <w:lang w:val="en-CA"/>
            </w:rPr>
        </w:pPr>
        <w:bookmarkStart w:name="para10000" w:id="10000"/>
        <w:r>
            <w:rPr>
                <w:rStyle w:val="Heading1Char"/>
                <w:rFonts w:cs="Arial"/>
                <w:b w:val="false"/>
                <w:bCs w:val="false"/>
                <w:color w:val="000000" w:themeColor="text1"/>
                <w:sz w:val="22"/>
                <w:szCs w:val="22"/>
                <w:lang w:val="en-CA"/>
            </w:rPr>
            <w:t xml:space="preserve">Some Text. </w:t>
        </w:r>
        <w:hyperlink r:id="rId2">
            <w:bookmarkStart w:name="replacetext_2_0" w:id="0"/>
            <w:r>
                <w:rPr>
                    <w:rStyle w:val="Heading1Char"/>
                    <w:rFonts w:cs="Arial"/>
                    <w:b w:val="false"/>
                    <w:bCs w:val="false"/>
                    <w:color w:val="000000" w:themeColor="text1"/>
                    <w:sz w:val="22"/>
                    <w:szCs w:val="22"/>
                    <w:lang w:val="en-CA"/>
                </w:rPr>
                <w:t xml:space="preserve">Age of 18 years</w:t>
            </w:r>
            <w:bookmarkEnd w:id="0"/>
            <w:r>
                <w:rPr>
                    <w:rStyle w:val="Heading1Char"/>
                    <w:rFonts w:cs="Arial"/>
                    <w:b w:val="false"/>
                    <w:bCs w:val="false"/>
                    <w:color w:val="000000" w:themeColor="text1"/>
                    <w:sz w:val="22"/>
                    <w:szCs w:val="22"/>
                    <w:lang w:val="en-CA"/>
                </w:rPr>
                <w:t xml:space="preserve">.</w:t>
            </w:r>
        </w:hyperlink>
        <w:r>
            <w:rPr>
                <w:rStyle w:val="Heading1Char"/>
                <w:rFonts w:cs="Arial"/>
                <w:b w:val="false"/>
                <w:bCs w:val="false"/>
                <w:color w:val="000000" w:themeColor="text1"/>
                <w:sz w:val="22"/>
                <w:szCs w:val="22"/>
                <w:lang w:val="en-CA"/>
            </w:rPr>
            <w:t xml:space="preserve"> Some text</w:t>
        </w:r>
        <w:bookmarkEnd w:id="10000"/>
    </w:p>
```

**Expected output:**

```
<w:p>
<w:pPr>
    <w:pStyle w:val="ChapterTitle"/>
    <w:spacing w:before="0" w:after="0"/>
    <w:jc w:val="both"/>
    <w:rPr></w:rPr>
</w:pPr>
<w:bookmarkStart w:id="0" w:name="para10000"/>
<w:r>
    <w:rPr>
        <w:rStyle w:val="Heading1Char"/>
        <w:rFonts w:cs="Arial"/>
        <w:b w:val="false"/>
        <w:bCs w:val="false"/>
        <w:color w:val="000000" w:themeColor="text1"/>
        <w:sz w:val="22"/>
        <w:szCs w:val="22"/>
        <w:lang w:val="en-CA"/>
    </w:rPr>
    <w:t xml:space="preserve">Some Text. </w:t>
</w:r>
<w:hyperlink r:id="rId2">
    <w:del w:id="0" w:author="Unknown Author" w:date="2021-12-13T20:35:11Z">
        <w:bookmarkStart w:id="1" w:name="replacetext_2_0"/>
        <w:r>
            <w:rPr>
                <w:rStyle w:val="Heading1Char"/>
                <w:rFonts w:cs="Arial"/>
                <w:b w:val="false"/>
                <w:bCs w:val="false"/>
                <w:color w:val="000000" w:themeColor="text1"/>
                <w:sz w:val="22"/>
                <w:szCs w:val="22"/>
                <w:lang w:val="en-CA"/>
            </w:rPr>
            <w:delText>Age of 18 years</w:delText>
        </w:r>
    </w:del>
    <w:ins w:id="1" w:author="Unknown Author" w:date="2021-12-13T20:35:14Z">
        <w:bookmarkEnd w:id="1"/>
        <w:r>
            <w:rPr>
                <w:rStyle w:val="Heading1Char"/>
                <w:rFonts w:cs="Arial"/>
                <w:b w:val="false"/>
                <w:bCs w:val="false"/>
                <w:color w:val="000000" w:themeColor="text1"/>
                <w:sz w:val="22"/>
                <w:szCs w:val="22"/>
                <w:lang w:val="en-CA"/>
            </w:rPr>
            <w:t>Age of 18</w:t>
        </w:r>
    </w:ins>
    <w:r>
        <w:rPr>
            <w:rStyle w:val="Heading1Char"/>
            <w:rFonts w:cs="Arial"/>
            <w:b w:val="false"/>
            <w:bCs w:val="false"/>
            <w:color w:val="000000" w:themeColor="text1"/>
            <w:sz w:val="22"/>
            <w:szCs w:val="22"/>
            <w:lang w:val="en-CA"/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:t>.</w:t>
    </w:r>
</w:hyperlink>
<w:r>
    <w:rPr>
        <w:rStyle w:val="Heading1Char"/>
        <w:rFonts w:cs="Arial"/>
        <w:b w:val="false"/>
        <w:bCs w:val="false"/>
        <w:color w:val="000000" w:themeColor="text1"/>
        <w:sz w:val="22"/>
        <w:szCs w:val="22"/>
        <w:lang w:val="en-CA"/>
    </w:rPr>
    <w:t xml:space="preserve"> Some text</w:t>
</w:r>
<w:bookmarkEnd w:id="0"/>
</w:p>
```

Comment: Using 3.3.6 docx4j version.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use docx4j 3.x! You should be using some recent release...

If you want to use XPath to find your bookmark, you can use

```
String xpath = "//w:bookmarkStart[@w:name='replacetext_2_0']";
```

in the docx4j sample code at https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/docx4j-samples-docx4j/src/main/java/org/docx4j/samples/XPathQuery.java

An alternative approach would be to look at https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/docx4j-samples-docx4j/src/main/java/org/docx4j/samples/BookmarksReplaceWithText.java

Comment: Do you mean using latest version will solve the below issue. javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: The prefix "w" for element "w:hyperlink" is not bound.